# biblatex/biber: removing a comma between reference and postnote argument

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm using biblatex/biber for some months and I'm quite happy with it. But I'm facing a little problem, for which I can't find a solution.

Even if the postnote argument is not a page number, biblatex/biber still inserts a comma between the reference and the postnote. So when I type this:

```
\footcite[En analysant le problème tant du
point de vue de la composition que de la réception, V. Jouve note que
la lecture d'un roman repose à la fois sur la décodification
sémiotique, l'illusion référentielle et l'investissement affectif du
lecteur.]{JouveV1992}.
```

I get this:

> Vincent Jouve, *L'Effet personnage dans le roman*, op. cit., En analysant le
>   problème tant du point de vue de la composition que de la réception, V. Jouve 
>   note que la lecture d'un roman repose à la fois sur la décodification
>   sémiotique, l'illusion référentielle et l'investissement affectif du
>   lecteur.

I would like to remove the comma just after "op. cit." so I can add, in the postnote, a new sentence starting with capital.

Thanks in advance for your help.
best regards

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: To me it seems that the text you write there is so long that it warrants a `\footnote{\cite{JouveV1992}. Blah-di-blah}`. Or try `\AtNextCite{\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addperiod\space}}` just before the relevant citation.

Comment: Yes, I usually employ the "footnote+cite" solution. But in some cases (for instance when it is a reference repeated in sequence) it produces an "ibid" that starts with no capital. You must add some text (Cf. See) before it, which is sometimes a little annoying. Anyway it happens so often in my thesis that I wanted to know how to solve this problem with no indirect solutions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well in that case you could do with `\footnote{\Cite{JouveV1992}. Blah-di-blah}` to make sure the citation always starts upper-case. Actually, it is probably a good habit to use the capitalised (or should that be capitalising) versions at the beginning of sentences.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! ...and sorry about my bad english :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For long discussions such as this, it might be better to use a `\cite` in a `\footnote`. I tend to use the post- and prenotes only for short comments and pinpoints, for longer texts other solutions might be better. To get capitalisation right, we need

```
\footnote{\Cite{JouveV1992}. Blah-di-blah}
```

`\Cite` with a capital `C`.

If you want to stick with the postnote, you will have to change the `\postnotedelim` at the next citation

```
\AtNextCite{\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addperiod\space}}
```

right before the offending citation.